# Spanish language not working after update

Tags: errors, lyx, babel

I've recently updated my Lyx to the new 2.1 version. But when I try to compile my documents (in spanish language), I obtain the following "Undefined control sequence" error:

```
 \StartBabelCommands
                         *{spanish}{captions}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I've set Spanish as my language in Settings > Language, and also I tried to add the `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` on the preamble. No results. 
I really don't know why this happen. In my old Lyx 2.0 that configuration worked perfectly.

**Edit: here you have the LaTeX output by LyX (Minimal working example). This code produces the error mentioned above:**
I've also tried to compile this LaTeX outside LyX and it doesn't work.

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>}}

\begin{document}
Una fórmula:
\[
E=mc^{2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried to compile your document without LyX? Does it happen for other documents too, which do not require Spanish language settings?

Comment: I've only used LyX. It works with English. I've also tried with some random languages and it works with Latin, Slovak, Danish...

Comment: Can you please always post a minimal example for questions like this? http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: The minimal working example: write "hola" in document and try to compile it with Spanish. It won't work even with that simple word. It won't work in ANY document in Spanish. So I'm sure it's not a conflict with other Latex code in the document.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to improper updating procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The problem was that the babel package was outdated. I runned MikTeX 2.9 Updater (Administrator) and I updated all the packages. After that and a LyX reconfiguration it works now.